# Not annotated parameter overrides @NonNullApi parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, nullable

I've been looking around other questions and I still don't understand what's going on here.
I have this class:

```
package com.test.service.database.converter;

import com.test.service.database.dao.DocumentType;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class DocumentStringConverter implements Converter<DocumentType, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(DocumentType documentType) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(documentType).map(DocumentType::type).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Which implements this Spring interface:

```
package org.springframework.core.convert.converter;

import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Converter<S, T> {

    @Nullable
    T convert(S source);

    default <U> Converter<S, U> andThen(Converter<? super T, ? extends U> after) {
        Assert.notNull(after, "After Converter must not be null");
        return (S s) -> {
            T initialResult = convert(s);
            return (initialResult != null ? after.convert(initialResult) : null);
        };
    }
}
```

And IntelliJ gives a warning on the param in

```
public String convert(DocumentType documentType) {
```

that states

> Not annotated parameter overrides @NonNullApi parameter

> documentType – the source object to convert, which must be an instance of S (never null)

Why is this? What does it mean, since Converter is annotated with `@Nullable`? And how do I solve this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Spring Official Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNullApi.html):

> A common Spring annotation to declare **that parameters and return values are to be considered as non-nullable** by default for a given package.

Here's the `org/springframework/core/convert/converter/package-info.java`:

```java
/**
 * SPI to implement Converters for the type conversion system.
 */
@NonNullApi       // !!!!!!!!!!!!
@NonNullFields
package org.springframework.core.convert.converter;
```

`@NonNullApi` can be overridden at the method level with the `@Nullable` annotation to prevent the warning for a method that might return null, and that's what you see in `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Converter<S, T> {

    /**
     * Convert the source object of type {@code S} to target type {@code T}.
     * @param source the source object to convert, which must be an instance of {@code S} (never {@code null})
     * @return the converted object, which must be an instance of {@code T} (potentially {@code null})
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the source cannot be converted to the desired target type
     */
    @Nullable            // !!!!!!!!!!
    T convert(S source);
```

On your overridden method, you don't specify the `@Nullable` annotation and thus the warning.

Comment: I take it the
"// !!!!!!!!!!!!" is there because of how counterinvtuitive it is to have the method Nullable but not the class?

Comment: No that's just my comment to mark a particular line of interest =)

Comment: To fix this I added the package-info.java and added annotations NonNullFields
NonNullApi and it works for me. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed this warning by adding a [`package-info.java`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-package-info) in the same package where the class file is present:

```java
@NonNullApi
package com.my.demo;

import org.springframework.lang.NonNullApi;
```